# Encountering problems with Thread.sleep in Swing

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

This program was written to count from 0 to 1000 but it just goes straight to 1000 without displaying the counting process. I have written similar code using a progress bar and `Thread.sleep()` method and it works perfectly.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class project extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton CountUpButton = new JButton("Count up");
    JButton CountDownButton = new JButton("Count Down");
    JButton ResetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    JTextField NumberField = new JTextField();
    int count = 0;

    public project(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        setSize(500, 300);
        add(NumberField);
        add(CountUpButton);
        add(CountDownButton);
        add(ResetButton);
        CountUpButton.addActionListener(this);
        CountDownButton.addActionListener(this);
        ResetButton.addActionListener(this);
        NumberField.setText("0");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        if(CountUpButton.hasFocus()){        
            count = Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText());
            try{
            while(count < 1000){
                count = count + 1;
                NumberField.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                Thread.sleep(100);                
            }
            }catch(InterruptedException r){
                r.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(CountDownButton.hasFocus()){
            count = Integer.parseInt(NumberField.getText());
            try{
                while(count > 0){
                    count -= 1;
                    NumberField.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(count));
                    Thread.sleep(100);                    
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException r){
                r.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(ResetButton.hasFocus()){
            NumberField.setText("0");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new project();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a wild guess, but as JTextFields usually have some initial value and then are modified by the user, and aren't expected to be modified programmatically like this, maybe you have to explicitly repaint it? Just a guess, but easy to try until someone comes up with the real answer. :-)

Comment: `actionPerformed(...)` is called in the UI thread, and you're blocking it with the calls to `Thread.sleep(...)`.  The UI cannot update until `actionPerformed(...)` returns.

Comment: Ok, my wild guess was wildly wrong, sorry. The comment from Kevin and the answer from Basil make sense to me (and I'm somewhat chagrined I didn't think of it, but it's been a while since I did AWT/Swing stuff.)

Answer (score 3):

Any long-running task should be run in a separate thread. Your use of Thread.sleep certainly qualifies as long-running.

By running in the Swing user-interface thread, no updates can be rendered in that user-interface until your code completes. Instead your counting should be spawned in another thread. That other thread should periodically update the user interface in a thread-safe manner using the SwingWorker.

Study up on [launching threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) such as a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), the Swing [event-dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT), and SwingWorker.

## Swing Timer

A simpler approach might be the [Swing Timer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) ([Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)), not to be confused with [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). It will do much of the thread-handling work for you. But I have no experience with it.

Comment: Using a Swing `Timer` would be more common (and simpler) for an 'animated counter'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Added mention and link for Swing Timer. Thanks.

Comment: *"It purports to do much of the thread-handling work for you"*  Code statements called in the `actionPerformed` of the `ActionListener` on which it is based are *guaranteed* to be called on the EDT.  It is not a place to be doing stuff that is truly a heavy load for the CPU (e.g. complex rendering to an image) or network or file intensive operations, but it is good for 'short duration' repeating tasks that deal mostly with GUI elements.